# Derived Distribution - Joint Probability

Tags: probability

I am trying to find the

```
1. P(Z < z)    :: 0 < z < 1
2. P(Z < z)    :: z > 1
```

When

```
Z = Y / X  :: both x and y are uniformally distributed between 0 and 1
f(x, y) = 1
```

I am just confused on the logic to get started.

Comment: I know how to do with 2 variables. 3 variables is throwing me off. When I do the triple integral of the f(x,y), I don't know what to set as the boundaries of each integral.

Comment: double* integral. I am confused on the logic aspect of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will find the cumulative distribution function $F(z)$ of $Z$, for the case $0\le z\le 1$, and leave the case $z\gt 1$ to you.

**Draw** the standard $1\times 1$ square in the coordinate plane. For fixed $z\l 1$, **draw** the line $y=xz$.

We have $\frac{Y}{X}\le z$ if $(X,Y)$ lands in the part of the unit square which is below the line $y=zx$.

This region is a triangle with base $1$. To find the height of the triangle, find where $y=zx$  meets $x=1$. So the height of our triangle is $z$. Its area is therefore $\frac{z}{2}$. Divide by $1$ (the area of the square) to find our probability.

We get $\frac{z}{2}$. For the density function in the interval $0\lt z\lt 1$, differentiate.

For $z\gt 1$, the geometry is a little different, and a little harder, but the same basic idea applies.

Comment: Can we solve this via integration as well? Such that we do something like ... P(Y/X < z) which leads to P(X < zY) and we integrate from 0 to zy with respect to X and then integrate from 0 to z with respect to Y.

Comment: Yes, we can find the area of the triangle using integration. For $z\le 1$, integrate 1 with respect to $y$ from $y=0$ to $y=zx$, then integrate with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $1$. If you prefer to integrate first with respect to $x$, then $x$ goes from $y/z$ to $1$, and then $y$ goes from $0$ to $z$. For $z\gt 1$, it is easier to find first the probability of the complement.

Comment: How did you derive those integration boundaries? I am really lost on that part. If you can quickly explain that without the use of the triangle, it would be really good. I am asking because in many cases, the shape might be hard to tell quickly. I am referring to the part where you integrated `x` from `0` to `1`. Thank you for your help! Means a lot.

Comment: Additionally, when I do this integration, it seems like I am finding the marginal PDF and not the CDF. Is this true? The integration is starting to look very similar to the marginal PDF integration, however in this case I get a CDF and not the PDF. Why is that happening?

Comment: In this kind of problem, the region of integration (the "geometry") is so basic that I would strongly suggest always to pin it down. I have solved this kind of problem for too many years, but still always draw a picture. For example, in the integration for $z\le 1$, integrating first with respect to $x$, you had the bounds wrong. we go from the line $y=zx$ (so $x=y/z$) to $x=1$.

Comment: In my answer, I found the cdf of $Z$ for $z\le 1$. For the pdf, differentiate (we get $1/2$). I had left that part to you.

Comment: What I meant to say was that meant to say was that. The integration looks a lot like this ... http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/b/b/7bb26b5d4202fb8db4c2e03a21345ced.png
However, we are getting the CDF while the wikipedia image gets the PDF. Why is that?

Comment: That is another way of attacking the problem. To carry it out correctly, you still need control over the geometry. The method. sometimes called the method of transformations, tends to give students more difficulty.

Comment: Last question...how is what we did any different from that (apart from the final answer being a CDF vs PDF)? I mean everything else looks the same to me semantically atleast. I apologize, I am still relatively new to this.

Comment: One way to think about the difference is as follows. We found the cdf by integrating **twice** (double integral) and then differentiated to find the pdf. **One** of the integrations can be omitted, roughly speaking by differentiating under the integral sign (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus). That is how one obtains the formula you refer to.

Comment: But here you are dealing with 3 variables. So to get the marginal PDF of Z, you have integrate with respect to X and Y. However, you are doing the same for here as well for the CDF.

Comment: We used area, but the same method (except we would really have to integrate) will work if we have a non-constant density in the unit square. In that case, you can integrate with respect to $y$. Then we differentiate under the integral sign. You are right, even after the differentiation there may be an integral left to compute.